# Vimeo video cannot insert in product page

Tags: magento2, vimeo

I am trying to add Vimeo video on product page, but having error that saying video not found.
I did check the video setting, it is fine and open to public. Anyone know why?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This problem already fixed about 1-2 months ago.

You can find the fix here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/31769

Answer (score 0):

https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360057035492?input_string=vimeo+video+not+found+by+path

This is Magento Bug MDVA-35092,  after apply the patch, it works fine

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me on version 2.3.4

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/f2231f8d953bb650c3462a824716fd8972c6bb6c